# Explain how this Java program prints out 65535

Tags: java

This  is the class with the main method.

```
import java.util.*; 
import java.io.*;
class Main {
    public static void main(String args[])
        System.out.println((int)(char)(byte)-1);
    }
}
```

Please explain how this prints out the result "65535".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's follow it, according to the **Java Language Specification**:

```
-1
```

[Integer Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1):

> An integer literal is of type `long` if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter `L` or `l` (ell); otherwise it is of type `int` ([§4.2.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1)).

So in hex that means:

```
0xFFFFFFFF {int -1}
```

---

```
(byte)0xFFFFFFFF
```

[Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) (`int` to `byte`):

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the *n* lowest order bits, where *n* is the number of bits used to represent type T. In addition to a possible loss of information about the magnitude of the numeric value, this may cause the sign of the resulting value to differ from the sign of the input value.

```
0xFFFFFFFF {int -1}  →  0xFF {byte -1}
```

---

```
(char)0xFF
```

[Widening and Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.4) (`byte` to `char`):

> First, the `byte` is converted to an `int` via widening primitive conversion ([§5.1.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2)), and then the resulting `int` is converted to a `char` by narrowing primitive conversion ([§5.1.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3)).

[Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) (`byte` to `int`):

> A widening conversion of a signed integer value to an integral type T simply sign-extends the two's-complement representation of the integer value to fill the wider format.

```
0xFF {byte -1}  →  0xFFFFFFFF {int -1}
```

[Narrowing Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.3) (`int` to `char`):

> A narrowing conversion of a signed integer to an integral type T simply discards all but the *n* lowest order bits, [...]

```
0xFFFFFFFF {int -1}  →  0xFFFF {char 65535}
```

---

```
(int)0xFFFF
```

[Widening Primitive Conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.2) (`char` to `int`):

> A widening conversion of a `char` to an integral type T zero-extends the representation of the `char` value to fill the wider format.

```
0xFFFF {char 65535}  →  0x0000FFFF {int 65535}
```

---

**Result: `65535`**

Answer (score 1):

`char` is not signed. `-1` (the integer negative one) becomes `Character.MAX_VALUE` (because of [**arithmetic underflow**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_underflow)). It's equivalent to

```
System.out.println((int) Character.MAX_VALUE);
```

and thus you get (the perhaps surprising) `65535`.